# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/criteria/Selection" error while using Hibernate in a JavaEE Maven project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm having a trouble using Hibernate in a Maven/JEE project, and still getting this error each time I try to use it (Hibernate).

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA as an IDE.

Here's what my pom.xml file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>panier</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.panier</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.29</version>
            </dependency>
<!--             https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.18</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

and I'm using a persistenence.xml as well :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Products_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- Persistence provider -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- Entity classes -->
        <class>main.java.model.Product</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_product"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Concerning my project structure, it's like the following :
[image: my project Structure]

but still get this error message :

[image: Error Message]

I think it may be related to an unloaded Jar, but still got no effective result after a long search.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have Hibernate and EclipseLink as dependencies?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli considering the pom.xml file, yes I do

Comment: And why? This does not make sense. you only need hibernate

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Exactly, I tried to add it after Hibernate didn't work

Comment: Where is the code you using the `Criteria` class? Can you show it? It is strange that you use it in code but cannot compile.

Comment: @WesternGun unfortunately, I'm not using the criteria

Comment: @SaadElattar try adding javax.persistence-api dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Maven not importing the Hibernate Jar, After importing it manually, it worked just fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please clean up your Maven pom.xml

You don't need EclipseLink and JPA spec. EclipseLink is another implementation and the JPA spec is a transitive dependency of Hibernate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>panier</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.panier</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.29</version>
            </dependency>
<!--             https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.18</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code or an example project on Github? It's not possible to help you otherwise